# Multiple IPv6 with single interface on Debian not working

Tags: ipv6

My VPS server assigned 1 IPv4 and 2 IPv6 addresses but only one seems to work.

My interfaces config

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 184.82.222.136
    gateway 184.82.222.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
iface eth0 inet6 static
    up echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/autoconf
    up echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/autoconf
    netmask 64
    gateway 2607:f878:0001:0aec:0000:0000:0000:0001
    address 2607:f878:1:aec::218a:4537
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet6 static
    up echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/autoconf
    up echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/autoconf
    netmask 64
    address 2607:f878:1:aec::d4bf:2d9d
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

and when I run **/etc/init.d/networking stop && /etc/init.d/networking** start I get

```
Deconfiguring network interfaces...done.
Configuring network interfaces...SIOCSIFFLAGS: Cannot assign requested address
Failed to bring up eth0:0.
done.
```

I read that my network card has something to do with it. Is it true? Do I need to talk to my VPS provider to manually assign the IP to this interface?
(Debian 6 with Xen.)

Update!
I tried new up and down technique and still not working.

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 184.82.222.136
    gateway 184.82.222.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
iface eth0 inet6 static
    up echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/autoconf
    up echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/autoconf
    netmask 64
    gateway 2607:f878:0001:0aec:0000:0000:0000:0001
    address 2607:f878:1:aec::218a:4537
    up ip addr add 2607:f878:1:aec::d4bf:2d9d dev eth0 label eth0:0
    down ip addr del 2607:f878:1:aec::d4bf:2d9d dev eth0 label eth0:0
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Still first IPv6 is working and the second one is not.

Comment: Why did you add the "label eth0:0"? Did you try to leave it out? And if you really need to use it, I think it should be placed before the "dev eth0".

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem. It works when I enter the "ip addr add" command after eth0 is up.

Comment: I had to contact my hosting provider to get if fixed, it was a problem at their end. I opened a ticket and they fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

The alias `eth0:0` interfaces are for IPv4, where traditionally multiple addresses per interface weren't allowed. (With the `ip` tool you can add multiple IPv4 and IPv6 addresses  to an interface, but `ifconfig` will not show the extra IPv4 addresses, so using `eth0:0` is still very common)

Change your config to:

```
up ip addr add 2607:f878:1:aec::d4bf:2d9d dev eth0
down ip addr del 2607:f878:1:aec::d4bf:2d9d dev eth0
```

and it should work.

Comment: It's common on Debian systems, anyway, where their horribly out of date wiki still recommends it. The rest of the Linux world has moved on to the new way of adding multiple IP addresses to interfaces.